# How to cite an article in the document (not the bibliography)

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

When I use somewhere in the input the

> \cite{ArticleM}

command, on the output I get the position of ArticleM in the Biobliography.

What if I want the name of the author written in that point as well? If I'm using the `cite` package, what command should I use to get that result?

Using, as an example, a `.tex` MWE I used in a previous question:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage{cite}
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\begin{document}
Here is the bib entry mentioned\cite{Wolf2003}

\bibliography{C:/Users/Giovanni/Desktop/PFG/Docear/data/profiles/default/docear}

\end{document}
```

I would like to have in the output:

> Here is the bib entry mentioned (Wolf et al.)[1]

Is this possible?

Thank you.

Comment: Why don't use `biblatex` and its command `\citeauthor*`?

Comment: This will cite the author on output and bibliography at the same time? Thank you @karlkoeller

Comment: A little late, but I've answered...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use the `biblatex` package with `numeric` style and the `\citeauthor*` command:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=numeric,backend=biber]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}


I want to cite~(\citeauthor*{aksin})\cite{aksin}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to use `bibtex` instead of `biber` change the backend to `backend=bibtex`

Comment: One last question @karlkoeller:
In `printbibliography`, you have to specify the path-to-bibfile between {}?

I didn't mentioned it but I don't know anything about `biblatex`. I'm quite new here. Thank you.

Comment: No, `\printbibliography` is just to print it. The command to load it is `\addbibresource`. You should do it there. Anyway, I suggest you to use paths relative to your `.tex` file

Answer (score 4):

You can do this using [`natbib`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/natbib) and its `\citeauthor` command (the numeric style was maintained by using the `unsrt` style):

```
\begin{filecontents*}{zz.bib}
@article{Wolf2003,
  title={The title},
  author={Wolf},
  journal={Journal of Articles},
  year={2003}
}
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\begin{document}
Here is the bib entry mentioned~\citeauthor{Wolf2003}\cite{Wolf2003}
\bibliography{zz}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Another option would be to switch to the powerful [`biblatex`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex) package and use its features.

Comment: I've already been told about biblatex. Honestly, I don't know how to use it. I've just downloaded a quick guide to begin with. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: @Josh while you get used to `biblatex`, my answer offers you the chance to get your desired output without using it.